# Using gulp externally from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I've installed `Visual Studio 2015` and working with a `MVC6` project. Inside Visual studio everything works, the task running runs and executes everything in my `gulp` configuration file.

When I try and build / deploy externally (using the command line), it fails since gulp appears to not be in the path.

The path for gulp is currently listed as

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates\DNX\CSharp\1033\StarterWeb\node_modules\.bin` from what I've read online this is a path isn't supposed to be in your global path but is only referenced when npm runs.

Is there a way for Visual Studio to install gulp (and other required tools) in a global context rather than in a local context, or should I just reference the above path in my PATH environment variable?

Comment: Why don't you install gulp globally from node js command prompt `npm install --global gulp`

Comment: I was just trying to avoid having two versions kicking around to manage :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio installs Node, Git, Bower and NPM in a special directory without adding them to the PATH.  The reason for this is simple; the product needs to work as designed for years to come, and Microsoft has no control over the evolution of these tools.  However, you can install the tools globally yourself and make both VS and the command line consume the same tooling by going to the Options dialog under the Tools menu and selecting "Projects and Solutions / External Web Tools" and setting the paths to the appropriate installation locations.

This works fine with current versions of Git, Bower, Node and NPM.  If it will work in two years is anybody's guess.  There's a Reset to Defaults button if things get out of hand.